# Nested <a> and <span> challenge

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Trying in vain to get a nested  link working within a nested span. [This](http://www.conservationenterprises.com/snippet.html) is a working test page for the code below to explain what I'm trying to do.

Any ideas on how to get this working in valid html? I guess it's either a nesting order or style syntax thing but I am at a loss. Any thoughts much appreciated.

```
<div id="greyback">
<ul id="scrollbox">
<li class="listcat">List header</li>
<li><a class="menu" href="#freeze">List item 1<span><b>This text has popped up because you have clicked the list item, which has an "a" tag and now has :focus. That "a" tag is the first of two.</b><br><br>What I am trying to do is to set the second "a" tag as a DIFFERENT "embedded" link in this box<span style="color: blue; background-color: yellow;">eg, here<a href="http://www.conservationenterprises.com" target="blank">This is the second (nested) "a" tag in this html nest.  It is a link to an external site. Instead of this being an always-visible link, I want it to sit within the yellow box in the first span (click the List item 1 to display).</a></span>
</a></span>
</li>
</a></span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#scrollbox  {margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 1em;  margin-bottom: 1em; width:19em; height:auto;  max-height: 21em; overflow:auto; border-bottom: 0.1em solid #FFA500; border-top: 0.1em solid #FFA500;}

#scrollbox a {float: left; color:#000000; text-decoration:none; width:18em; height: auto; margin-bottom: 0.5em; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em; text-align:left;}
#scrollbox a.menu {}
#scrollbox a span {display:none; position:absolute; left:0em; top:0;}
#scrollbox a span img {float: right; border:0; max-width:7.5em;}
#scrollbox a:hover {border: 0; color: #7ebb11; font-size:0.9em;}
#scrollbox a:hover span {border: 0; color: #535353;}
#scrollbox a span:focus {color: blue;}
#scrollbox a:active {border:none; color: #535353; text-decoration: none;}
#scrollbox a:focus {border:0em solid #000; outline:0;}
#scrollbox a:active span, #scrollbox li a:active span, #scrollbox a:focus span, #scrollbox li a:focus span  {display: block; width: 52.5em; min-height: 20em; height: auto; left: 1.5em; top:18em;  z-index:10; font-size:0.9em; text-align: left; padding: 1em; padding-bottom: 0em; background-color: #c3FFe3; color: #535353; border: solid #FFA500 0.25em;}
#scrollbox li a:active span span, #scrollbox li a:focus span span{display: block; width: auto; height: auto; min-height: 2em;  left: 25em; top:10em;  z-index:10; font-size:0.9em; text-align: left; padding: 1em; padding-bottom: 0em; background-color: transparent; color: #535353;  border: dashed red 1px;}

.ul#scrollbox {padding-left: 0.1em;}

#scrollbox li {float:left; list-style: none; background: url(blank.png) no-repeat left center; margin-left: 0em; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em;}
#scrollbox li.listcat {float: left; text-align:left; width: 18em; margin-left: 0em; margin-top: 0.1em; margin-bottom: 0.3em; padding-top:0.5em; color: green; font-size: 0.9em; font-weight:bold;}
```

Cheers
Patrick.

Comment: why not just use javascript to hide/show the extra box? it's much easier that way than trying to achieve all that in css(or are you planning to really just use pure css to fix that?)

Comment: @corroded I was hoping for CSS only as I wouldn't recognise javascript if it bit me, but if that's what it'll take...

Comment: there are easy javascript tutorials for this and there are tools that help like jquery(if you have the time you can check it out) i can try fixing you up a simple sample in awhile

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have your closing tags in the wrong place and I think you have spans misplaced but just validating will show you those errors.

Comment: thanks @rob the validation suggests doing things that would put the spanned <a> tags outside the <li> definition, making it hard (impossible?) for them to be styled... I wonder if there is a sequence/protocol eg all <a>s within <span>s or vice versa that generally works -  could you point out one of the wrong closing tag locations please?

Comment: @PaddyO -  
Work through it and you'll notice you are doing this:  
    <a><span></a></span>  
Which is illegal.

Comment: thanks, I see. Will give it a shot in the right order. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Rob, fixed those and managed to get almost all if it to validate, except because I one of the sequences has (and needs to have if I'm trying to make a spanned <a> that holds a second <a> active) <span><a><a></a></a></span> the W3C doesn't like it (specifically doesn't like the <a> within the other <a>. Now learning some javascript...

Comment: @PaddyO Learning javascript will not help if your markup's invalid. Don't nest A elements and it will be a lot easier on you.

Answer (score 0):

provided you are using jquery(or a similar javascript framework that uses the $ sign):

```
<div id="popup" style="display: hidden">
   <span><b>This text has popped up because you have clicked the list item, which has an "a" tag and now has :focus. That "a" tag is the first of two.</b>
</div>

<li>
  <a href="your first link" onclick="$('popup').setStyle('display: block;')">first link</a>
  <a href="second link">second link</a>
</li>
```

you could also use onfocus as substitute for onclick. if you don't have a javascript library, use document.getElementById('popup') instead of the $ sign.

here's a really simple tutorial on how to hide some divs in jquery: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: thanks for the jquery pointer, I'll take a look.  Always good to learn some more and it looks like that's what's needed.  Much appreciated.

Comment: no worries. im more of an xhtml/css person myself and i didn't want to touch JS with a ten-foot pole but apparently it is also good to learn it especially with frameworks(moo-tools, jquery, prototype). it GREATLY helps in making good UI and user experience :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll certainly need to use Javascript for this (although certainly not Jquery, especially if Javascript already seems foreign to you). Right now, you're trying to embed a link inside another link and I don't think that can ever work correctly.

I would suggest using unique `div` ids and the HTML DOM do display your divs and links. This is oversimplified, but something like this:

```
<div id="one"><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('two').style.display='block'">Link 1</a></div>
<div id="two" style="display: none;">Here it is</div>
```

W3Schools.com has a really good [Javascript tutorial](http://w3schools.com/js/default.asp) to get you started.

Edit: A couple of side notes. Learning Javascript fundamentals will be well worth your time. Also, try to always use [well-formed html](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.1).

Comment: Thank you, I will give Javascript a look.  Out of interest (although I always prefer "legal" where possible, Firefox interprets a piece of illegal code - <div> within a <ul> - beautifully at www.conservationenterprises.com/portfolio.html and does exactly what I want to do.  But I will persevere and get it right.